# Scroll listener for nested recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm developing an application in which my homepage populated with Recyclerview data with multiple view type with one horizontal Recyclerview and two vertical recycler view. So I have Recyclerview inside Recyclerview. I want to add scroll listener for second vertical Recyclerview but unable to add, because all scroll is handled by the main parent Recyclerview.
I tried to add scroller listener inside the adapter, it is working properly for horizontal Recycler view but not for vertical. How to make it work?

Comment: In short, you want to manage scroll inside scroll. right?

Comment: @DhruvPatel Yes, I'm trying to implement pagination for list inside list

Comment: Android Library to put a ListView inside a ScrollView without collapsing. https://github.com/paolorotolo/ExpandableHeightListView

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vertical recyclerview in nestedScrollView you need to implement scroll listener for nestedScrollView otherwise recyclerview's scroll listener wont be triggered. Here is how you can basically implement it and you can catch where to load more data for pagination feature

```
private void implementScrollListener() {

    //Scroll Listener for nestedScrollView. Note that it is used for pagination when user reaches the bottom.

    if(nestedScrollView != null){

        nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {

                if (scrollY > oldScrollY) {
                    //Scrolling down
                }
                if (scrollY < oldScrollY) {
                    //Scrolling up
                }

                if (scrollY == 0) {
                    //Reaches to the top
                }

                if (scrollY < (v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight())) {
                    //Reaches to the bottom so it is time to updateRecyclerView!
                    updateRecyclerView();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

If it is not the case that you use nestedScrollView, you could set `myRecyclerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` to make it scroll smoothly if you have several recyclerviews for your whole activity or fragment.

Hope this answer helps you,

Happy Coding.
Baki